# Python 3 unable to find file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subprocess, kml

My code is listed below. I am just trying to follow along with a tutorial. I am working on eventually applying this to a long list in a csv format. However, I cannot seem to get this simple code to run without throwing an error. The error is the dreaded FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import simplekml
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

# names in a list
names = ['test_1',
         'test_2',
         'test_3']

# lat and longs
latitudes = [47.547921, 48.018745, 47.982146]
longitudes = [-105.125498, -105.325687, -105.6547821]

# piecing together the name, long, and lat values into variable called locations
locations = pd.DataFrame({'names': names,
                          'longitudes': longitudes,
                          'latitudes': latitudes})

# creating an instance of the simplekml class
points_kml = simplekml.Kml()
# iterating over the locations variable 
for i in locations.itertuples():
    points_kml.newpoint(name=i.names, coords=[(i.longitudes, i.latitudes)])

# assigning the variable points_kml_path to where we want to save the file we are creating
points_kml_path = 'c:/Users/rexmo/Documents/points_kml.kml'
points_kml.save(points_kml_path)

# open with Google Earth Pro
#subprocess.call(['open', points_kml_path])
subprocess.run(['open', points_kml_path])
```

My traceback error is as follows:

```
runfile('C:/Users/rexmo/Documents/Work/spotter_problems/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/rexmo/Documents/Work/spotter_problems')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\rexmo\Documents\Work\spotter_problems\untitled0.py", line 31, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['open', points_kml_path])

  File "C:\Users\rexmo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File "C:\Users\rexmo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 104, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\rexmo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\rexmo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The file is being written to the directory listed in the code. I can double click the file in the folder and it is opened in Google Earth as expected. I am at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try pathlib?

```
from pathlib import Path

# Replace this line
points_kml_path = 'c:/Users/rexmo/Documents/points_kml.kml'
# With this
points_kml_path = Path.home() / 'Documents' / 'points_kml.kml'
# Edit, I don't know if you might need it as a string
points_kml_path = Path.home() / 'Documents' / 'points_kml.kml'
points_kml_path = str(points_kml_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your suggestions, both of them. I get the same error. I get a slightly different error if I do not include the points_kml_path str(points_kml_path)

Comment: That's strange! Could you post the slighty different error? If you do `list((Path.home() / 'Documents').glob('*'))`, what output do you get? Do you see your file in there?

Comment: If I do {print(list((Path.home() / 'Documents').glob('*')))} I get a list of all the files in the directory. The file that I want to open is there just as it should be. {WindowsPath('C:/Users/rexmo/Documents/points_kml.kml')} it is of course there with an entire list of other files but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found 2 different ways to get the result that I wanted, which was simply to fire up Google Earth with the points created in the above script. The first and seemingly less complicated is

```
import os
os.startfile(points_kml_path)
```

The other seemingly slightly less complicated way is

```
# Path to Google Earth exe
earth = 'c:\Program Files\Google\Google Earth Pro\client\googleearth.exe'
subprocess.run([earth, points_kml_path])
```

It seems weird that I would need to explicitly show the full path to the Google Earth executable. If there is another way I would still be interested in hearing about it.